# Can I use bootstrap 4 modals without jQuery?

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-4

I'm using React and Bootstrap 4 and everything is going OK but I want to display a modal and it's not showing up.

I have not included the Bootstrap JS files or jQuery. And I don't want to.

Can it be done?

Comment: yes. Use `reactstrap`

Answer (score 3):

You can use [Native JavaScript for Bootstrap](https://thednp.github.io/bootstrap.native/)